# Fragment y Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragment

Tengo una app android que utiliza firebase, todo va bien pero cuando intento eliminar un valor de la base desde un fragment mi app se detiene (pero si se elimina). He intentado eliminando el valor desde una actividad y todo funciona con normalidad. El problema radica en el fragment y quisiera saber si alguien puede ayudarme con esto. Muchas gracias.

```
private void removeTrustedContact() {  
        //Get Firebase reference  
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();  
        usersRef = database.getReference(References.USERS_REFERENCE);

        //Get data session
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(References.USER_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        phone = sharedPreferences.getString("phone", "");

        Task<Void> result = usersRef.child(phone).child("trustedContacts").child(phoneContact).removeValue();
        if(result.isSuccessful()){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Bien", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Mal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Jhan te sugiero realices el [tour]. Por otro lado en este caso es importante agregar el mensaje desplegado en el LogCat, a simple vista si context no es null, no veo que el problema suceda en el mètodo removeTrustedContact()

Comment: Por favor publica el log de error para poder brindarte una mejor ayuda.

Comment: mi primer sospechoso sería el context, pero sin más detalle sobre el error es imposible diagnosticar el problema.